# I need help reading a text file to print to the console

Tags: java

I having trouble figuring this out it supposed to print the contents of the txt file but i cant get it print.

This is the output im supposed to get.

Ingredient __________Amount Needed  ______  Amount In Stock

baking soda_________4.50 ________________4.00

sugar ______________6.50________________3.20

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;

public class Lab8b {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter file name : ");
  String filename = scan.nextLine();
  Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File(filename));

  while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
   String name = fileScan.nextLine();
   String ingredientName = fileScan.nextLine();
   double amountNeeded = Double.parseDouble(fileScan.nextLine());
   double amountInStock = Double.parseDouble(fileScan.nextLine());

   if (amountNeeded > amountInStock) {

    System.out.printf("Ingredient \t Amount Needed \t Amount in Stock");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("%10s", ingredientName);
    System.out.printf("%8.2f", amountNeeded);
    System.out.printf("%16.2f", amountInStock);
   } //end if 

   if (amountNeeded <= amountInStock) {
    System.out.println("Nothing");

   } //end while
  } //end if
 } //end main
} //end class
```

Comment: Please do not correct the errors in your code as that forces me to periodically update my answer.

Comment: The purpose of the question is to display the problem at hand. If my answer helped you, I'd appreciate it if you accepted it instead.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Could you show us your input (sample) to see what is wrong? Which error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems I found with your code:

1. You created a `while` loop to read the contents of the file, but you don't do anything with it.
2. Need to wrap the code in a try-catch since `FileNotFoundException` might be thrown.
3. You attempt to call `readLine()` from `filename` instead of `fileScan`

I've assumed that you need `amountNeeded` and `amountInStock` to be doubles even though you don't do any calculations with them. If this isn't the case, you can simply leave them as strings instead of parsing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter file name : ");
    String filename = scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();
    Scanner fileScan = null;

    try {
        fileScan = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
            String ingredientName = fileScan.nextLine();
            double amountNeeded = Double.parseDouble(fileScan.nextLine());
            double amountInStock = Double.parseDouble(fileScan.nextLine()); 

            System.out.printf("Ingredient \t Amount Needed \t Amount in Stock\n");
            System.out.printf("%10s", ingredientName);
            System.out.printf("%8.2f", amountNeeded);
            System.out.printf("%16.2f", amountInStock);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```